# It is possible to query supported SQL Server protocols from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

It is possible to query supported SQL Server protocols from C#?

For local development in our group I'd like to fallback to a supported protocol if TCP is not enabled, but use TCP as the default protocol.

Currently if the TCP protocol is not enabled there is a timeout issue as we prefix `tcp:` on our server instance.

[image]

Comment: SQL Server client libraries already do that. By adding that prefix you prevent the client from trying the other protocols.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean TCP is the default? The main thing is I need to keep TCP as the default even if say Shared Memory is enabled.

Comment: No, I mean that if you add `tcp` you prevent the client from trying multiple libraries. If you type `.` or `(local)` or  a computer name, the client will try the providers in turn to find which one can make a connection. If you hard-code the protocol, you prevent the client from doing that.

Comment: Why are you doing this though? Why not use a different connection string for development, staging and production? Both .NET Old and .NET Core support different configuration files for debug/release or different environments, eg Development, Staging, Production

Comment: Great point. For dev we can just not use it. Should have had my coffee first.

Comment: If you'd like to turn your comments into an answer, I will mark it as accepted.